# Twilio function deployed with TypeScript cannot find module @twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types

Tags: typescript, twilio, twilio-functions

I'm trying to migrate a Twilio functions repo to use TypeScript. I completely rewritten one of the functions via TypeScript and successfully tested it locally. However, after I deployed the function, it started returning 500 with the following error:
`"message": "Cannot find module '@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types'`

I'm trying to find out how I can correctly import and use types.

**Some context:**

- Mainly followed this guide: https://www.twilio.com/blog/twilio-functions-typescript
- Deployed the repo via:
  `twilio serverless:deploy --functions-folder build/src/functions --runtime node14 --override-existing-project`
- Before compiling to javascript my import statement looks like this:

  ```
  import '@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types';
  import * as VoiceResponse from '@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime- 
     types/node_modules/twilio/lib/twiml/VoiceResponse';
  import { Context, ServerlessCallback, ServerlessFunctionSignature, TwilioClient } from 
    '@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/types';
  ```
- And after compiling the import statement looks like this:

  ```
  require("@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types");
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried adding the type dependency `@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types` as production dependency rather than a dev dependency via npm.

```
npm i @twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types -P
```

I deployed the function again after this change. Now, I'm not getting the 500 error and the function works as expected.

Comment: Accepting this workaround as an answer until someone provides a better solution...

Comment: In the blog post you followed, the `@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types` were installed as a production dependency, not a dev dependency, so this is the answer.